# Minimum API Level 14 required

Tags: android

I'm making an android project, pretty much i'm a noob, i need to make a project which will support the latest version too, but should be compatible with at least 2.3.3 version of android, but when i set my target to 2.3.3, compile with 2.3.3 and minimum to 2.3.3, now when i got to create a blank activity, it says minimum api level 14 required, how to achieve that or i can't make projects for api level below 14, i'm including images to explain it better
[image: this is the screen where i provide various details]

[image: and this where i'm stuck]

is there anyway i can achieve what i want to achieve?

Comment: this will come up with default action bar that will support >ICS. so you can remove the theme and your action bar/ menu also or uncheck the create activity and create your own.

Comment: for compatible with at least 2.3.3 version you just need set Minimum required sdk to api 10, change other to maximum api.

Answer (score 1):

### Why are you getting this error message?

The template which you are trying to include in your application uses features (like the actionbar) that requires an API level higher than 14, in the first step of the wizard, you selected 10 and it's < 14 and that's why you are getting this error message.

### Resolution:

As you want to develop an application with 2.3 compatibility, select below configurations:

- Minimum required SDK: API 10 (2.3.3)
- Target SDK: Select any of the platform >= 4.0
- Compile with: Select any of the platform >= 4.0

Answer (score 0):

you should set your Min SDK to API 10 and your target SDK to latest android API (currently 19).
set these in your manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```